# How to make a docker workflow for multiple processes

Tags: bash, docker

I am doing a lot of media related tasks using content that is processed in different Docker containers and I would like some guidance on how to create a simple, streamlined workflow. Specifically I am not sure when to use shell scripts and when to use Dockerfiles.

The common sequence of events is:

1. Convert an input video to a sequence of images
2. Process that sequence of images
3. Convert the processed images back to a video
4. Save this video on the host

Each of these is run with a different `docker run` command. I want to script these processes so that I do not have to sit at the command line and type `docker run image_name etc. etc.` every single time I want to do this.

**Step 1.** is run as the following:

`docker run -v $PWD:/temp/ jrottenberg/ffmpeg -i /temp/$SRC_VIDEO_DIR/$FILENAME /temp/$OUTPUT_IMAGE_DIR/$OUTPUT_IMAGE_BASENAME%06d.bmp`

**Step 2.** is run as the following:

`docker run -v $PWD/$OUTPUT_IMAGE_DIR:/notebook/raisr/test -v $PWD/$OUTPUT_LARGER_IMAGE_DIR:/notebook/raisr/results $DOCKER_IMAGE /bin/bash -c "source activate superres; cd /notebook/raisr; python test.py"`

**Step 3.** is run as the following:

`docker run -v $PWD:/temp/ jrottenberg/ffmpeg -framerate $FPS -i /temp/$OUTPUT_IMAGE_DIR/$OUTPUT_IMAGE_BASENAME%06d.bmp -c:v qtrle -pix_fmt rgb24 /temp/output_video/$OUTPUT_FILENAME`

The easiest way to do this seems like to create a shell script with those three commands in them and just run that script.  The annoying thing with that is that I have to edit the shell script and change the input path of the video file each time.  Also calling 3 commands in Step 2. does not seem like a common practice.

I realize that I could use the `RUN` option in a Dockerfile to specify that those commands are automatically run when the docker file is built, but mounting volumes via a Dockerfile and getting data *out* of the running container and to the host has been a large pain. And some of these commands depend on a Docker image being installed locally, with a specific name (the variable `$DOCKER_IMAGE` in step 2. above.

So:

1. **When you have multiple `docker run` commands, each relying on each others data, what is the correct, scalable way to run these commands?**
2. **When do people use shell scripts and when do people use Dockerfiles to manage multiple jobs?**
3. **Is it good practice to have a Dockerfile run a job that processes media or should this be done from a shell script as a `docker run` command?**

Comment: Why would you need to manually edit anything in the shell script? A bash script can accept cli arguments.

Comment: Why do you want Docker at all here?  It seems like you could install ffmpeg once, write a straightforward shell script, and not deal with the `-v` option chains at all (much less the need for root permission).

Comment: @DavidMaze because this script needs to run on multiple different servers and needs to be reproducible.

Comment: Why doesn't the second part take the filename as argument? Does it affect the output? `The annoying thing with that is that I have to edit the shell script and change the input path of the video file each time.` - This is very false.

Comment: @KamilCuk so the right way to handle multiple `docker run` commands is through a shell script?

Comment: There is no "right way". If you feel you have too much logic in your script, it is becoming too long, the quoting becomes unreadable, then you write a script. Imagine it's a poem. Would you write your poem as a one long line or write a whole book about it? It depends on the poem - is it long, short or does it rhyme? The `bash -c 'source something ; cd something ; execute something ;` looks simply ok, but if you would add some `xargs` and `printf`s and `if`s and `while`s you would move to a script. One could argue everything that works is the right way.